# equivalent of "canvas" in React Native

Tags: canvas, react-native

I am currently working on an image processing mobile App based on React-Native. However, I can't find any related documents about the image crop, zoom, pan, and save functions (which can be easily achieved by the HTML5 canvas element) on the React-Native official site.

I also do some google searches, but only find an "unmaintained" react-native-canvas (https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-canvas). Is there any equivalent of the "canvas" in React Native?

Comment: `react-native-canvas` does seem to be being maintained -- a new release was produced in 2017 and a bugfix was released recently.  It is, however, very slow in my experience and therefore probably not useful for any but the simplest applications.

Comment: @Jules what is the correct approach for vector in react? svg? canvas? png? i want to make a background image with triangles that has no quality loss and at the same time is quite lightweight

Answer (score 38):

`react-native-canvas` maintainer here. Since this question was asked a lot has changed in the library: it's the most complete and compatible canvas component for React Native featuring advanced features like `Path2D` and gradients, and unlike the default web view canvas it renders in high DPI.

The component is slower compared to other React Native components because behind the scenes it uses a `WebView` to render. The communication with it is optimised though and in many ways resemble the way React Native renders native views. The trade-off is the library doesn't require any native installation and relies only on the React Native JavaScript runtime and the native `WebView`

There was an idea to render the canvas in the React Native JavaScript runtime though no-one has made a feature complete no-DOM canvas on a JavaScript runtime before so it will take a decent amount of effort to implement.

From our experience at K Health it's possible to render fast enough graphics for responsive user interaction but not fast enough for full animation. The component is used in our app which has thousands of users.

The contributors and users of `react-native-canvas`, including myself, are very willing to help and if you have any question you can feel free to open an issue or send an email.

Comment: I'm creating a RN project that takes images from the camera roll and does [pixel sorting](http://satyarth.me/articles/pixel-sorting/) on them. In the browser this would normally be done by taking in image data, manipulating it, and obviously writing it to the canvas. Do you think your library is something I could use to achieve this in React Native? I could do some other hack and process the images with phantomjs and save them then fetch them but i'd rather do it all in RN.

Comment: Yes, I think you can.

Comment: Great thanks for the reply! I will continue experimenting with it.

Comment: react-native-canvas looks useful, but I was unable to draw beyond a 300x150 rectangle. The entire canvas does appear in the correct background color, but my beginPath/moveTo/lineTo/stroke calls seem to do nothing beyond 300x150 from the top left of the canvas. Any ideas?

Comment: To set height and weight just set them for the canvas: `canvas.height = 400; canvas.width = 600;`

Comment: @IddanAaronsohn Does rendering of .tiff image is supported by  https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas ?

Comment: It's really up to the web browser of the device. You can check support here: https://tiff.net/browser-support

Comment: "though no-one has made a feature complete no-DOM canvas on a JavaScript runtime before" - how about https://github.com/phoboslab/Ejecta, ios only but a good start. Just wanted to chip in

Comment: @IddanAaronsohn Is there any tutorial for this? I want to do a drawing app where I need to draw rectangle square etc and free shapes. Is it possible. And any tutorial or a hint on how to do that ?

Answer (score 13):

Well, after two years, there is a new choice for you:

https://alibaba.github.io/GCanvas/

This "GCanvas" is designed for native environment to run canvas2d & WebGL APIs.

See

https://alibaba.github.io/GCanvas/docs/Integrate%20GCanvas%20on%20ReactNative.html

Comment: It looks like an interesting project, but it doesn't really seem to be ready for production use yet. I've been unable to get it to compile on either iOS or Android, and the documentation is a little sparse.  Could be very good when it is ready, though.

Comment: @Jules could you give more information about the build failing? environment and error message would be good.

Comment: Does it manage touch events ? Looks not from the documentation

Comment: @ShaofeiCheng I've been trying to make us this GCanvas on ReactNative but I can't get it running either. I'm just hit with build errors where RTCGCanvasView.h can't find React/RTCView.h. Could the docs be out of date? I'd love to give this library a try as I need RN->Canvas communication performance..

Comment: I've managed to get this one compiling and working with this fork: https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas.  Performance seems stellar so far.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few options that are "similar" but not the exact same. My suggestions would be...

- [React Native SVG](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) - Feels a lot like the SVG web components we are all familiar with. You can do lots with this library even animations.
- [ART](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/ART) (the React Native version [found here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/ART)) - A "React Native" version of the React ART library, which in turn is an extension of the library ART [found here](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/art). It ships with React Native but I don't think it's yet been integrated in the default setup so it's in your node_modules folder and needs to be imported into XCode (the discussion is [found here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4789)). I usually drag the project file out of the node_modules folder where it is located (`node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ART/Art.xcodeproj`) into the libraries folder in your React Native XCode project navigator. If it asks to copy resources click yes. Afterwards, go into your project settings file -> general -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries then press the plus icon. Search for ART and add it as a dependency.

**Note:** If you just started on react-native following the official "Getting Started" guide in the last few month, the default guide is to use "expo". And [React Native SVG](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) is by default included in the expo build. So using it would be a whole lot easier.

Comment: The main problem with React Native ART is that it seems to be entirely undocumented.  There's a project to write documentation for it [here](https://github.com/react-native-china/react-native-ART-doc/blob/master/doc.md) that could  be useful.

Comment: Seems like there's *some* documentation now for ART, but yeah still needs some work.

Answer (score 3):

Since Alibaba GCanvas [feat: delete weex bridge & reactive bridge](https://github.com/alibaba/GCanvas/commit/1bbee40a16c0c5da58698e2892ba33f836eedb70) and it's final release broke the compiling on Android, here comes the [@flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas) npm package.

After months work, [@flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas) runs well on Android and iOS, fix several bugs and add `feat: support drawImage() from require('some.png') on Android, iOS and Web` described in [Changelog.md](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas/blob/master/docs/Changelog.md), refactor with the detailed [Example As Usage](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas#example-as-usage) in README.md.

With [Performance Test Result](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas#performance-test-result), and [Convenient With Browser-like canvas APIs](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas#convenient-with-browser-like-canvas-apis) with the easily `<canvas/>` ported example [react-native-particles-bg](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-particles-bg) runs on Android, iOS and Web, `@flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas` is the best choice for now :P